# Android searchView not in actionBar remove focus

Tags: android, searchview

OK, this question has been asked many times and I have looked through many topics about it but I can not get it to work.

My `searchView` is not on the actionBar so I can't use `collapseActionView()`

I have tried

```
searchView.clearFocus();//this closes the keyboard but does not remove focus
getActivity().getCurrentFocus().clearFocus(); //basically the same as above
searchView.setQuery("", false); //this clears the query and drops the keyboard
searchView.setIconified(true);  // but the search retains focus and keyboard pops up again
```

No matter what I try I can not remove the focus from the `searchView` after it has been selected

Comment: Have you tried setting the focus to any other dummy view ? check this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117967/how-to-remove-focus-without-setting-focus-to-another-control

Comment: @Ramesh thank you very much, that thread helped me out. I tried the dummy view first, but did not work. Probably doing something wrong. I did get it to work by setting my layout to be focusable and setting that when I have made my search query

Comment: it would be good to post working solution as answer i hope :)

Answer (score 10):

To clear focus from my searchView after executing my query I first had to add

```
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

to my parent layout of the activity. Then in the activity

```
    LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout) activity.findViewById(R.id.my_layout);
    myLayout.requestFocus();
```

This will take the focus away from the searchView. All the info I needed was here [How to remove focus without setting focus to another control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117967/how-to-remove-focus-without-setting-focus-to-another-control)

Comment: android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" works for me