# Clear focus of AutoCompleteTextView on soft keyboard close

Tags: android, android-layout, android-softkeyboard, autocompletetextview

I have a simple AutoCompleteTextView in linear layout. I couldn't detect the keyboard close event. How to remove the focus of AutoCompleteTextView if soft keyboard is closed(Either finished editing or stopped editing without any text). Need simple code. I have tried some help given here but didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the second answer for the following question:

[Detecting when user has dismissed the soft keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3425932/detecting-when-user-has-dismissed-the-soft-keyboard/)
(the one marked correct is not a real solution)

all you need to do is apply it to AutoCompleteTextView and where it allows you to detect the close. set focus to another view as shown here

[How to remove focus without setting focus to another control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117967/how-to-remove-focus-without-setting-focus-to-another-control)

or you could do something using this:
[How to check visibility of software keyboard in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150078/how-to-check-visibility-of-software-keyboard-in-android)

Comment: yes.. but since you still want it to do other things... don't return true