# clearFocus() on empty editText is not working in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I tried to remove focus from empty editText but it isn't working correctly.
I called `clearFocus()` on `edittext` ,and then I placed break point at my `onFocusChanged()` function call.

Here is what happened:
`onFocusChanged()` called 4 times with the focused parameters values `false,true,false,true`.

What I thought was that `onFocusChanged()` must be called only once (with focused = false)

Sorry for my bad English. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15481511/5909692)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is happening because your `EditText` is the first focusable view.

**From the docs**,

> Note: When a View clears focus the framework is trying to give focus
>   to the first focusable View from the top. Hence, if this View is the
>   first from the top that can take focus, then all callbacks related to
>   clearing focus will be invoked after which the framework will give
>   focus to this view.

You can try setting a dummy focusable view above the `EditText` to clear the focus from it.

Answer (score 26):

In xml, make parent layout

```
  android:focusable="true"
  android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

and then call clearFocus on edit text and then call parent request focus

```
 mFragmentBase.editText.clearFocus();
 mFragmentBase.parentLayout.requestFocus();
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. I couldn't get my edittext's focus to clear but when requesting parentLayout focus after, it worked! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of clearing the focus from EditText create an empty view at the top of the layout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/focusableLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>
```

and declare a utility function to hide the keyboard like this

```
fun hideKeyboard(activity: Activity) {
    val inputMethodManager = activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager 
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.currentFocus?.windowToken, 0)
}
```

Finally when you need to clear focus just call

```
focusableLayout.requestFocus()
hideKeyboard(currentActivity)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please note you are answering a very old and already answered question. Here is a guide on [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).